# Faint power supply seen even when electrical switchboard sub switch is in the off position

Tags: power-supply, mains

A switchboard sub switch "P33" controls the electricity supply to the guest room.

When the sub switch "P33" is in the on position, the guest room wall sockets would have the full power supply. The tester plug shows the indicator lights brightly lit up in the correct configuration.

When the sub switch "P33" is in the off position, there is still a faint power supply on the wall sockets.

The sub switch "P33" is under the main switch "DB2", which is different from the main switch "DB1".

When the main switch "DB1" is off :
the guest room wall sockets would have no power.

When the main switch "DB1" is on, and the sub switches are all off :
the guest room wall sockets would also have no power.

When the main switch "DB1" is on, and some of the sub switches are on :
the guest room wall sockets would have a faint power supply.

It doesn’t matter which sub switches are on. The greater the number of sub switches turned on, the stronger the faint power supply. It just takes 4 sub switches turned on and we can see a faint power supply on the tester plug.

When there was a flash of lightning outside, I could see the tester plug briefly increase the indicator light intensity, then fall back to the faint light again.

By right, if the switchboard sub switch "P33" is off, there should not be any power at all on the guest room wall sockets.

I wonder what is causing this phenomenon.

Comment: Capacitive coupling. Use a low impedance meter rather than a high impedance meter and you won't get such ghost readings. Though, I would not expect something like a test indicator lamp to have high enough impedance to read the ghost signal. Lightning is another story...much more powerful.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Try the same experiments with a switched on (table) lamp plugged in to the sockets by where you're measuring. See what you measure when your sockets have a low resistance across them instead of very high resistance.

Comment: Make sure the (table) lamp has a filament bulb in it, not an energy-saving bulb. A simple electric kettle will also do.

Comment: What's a *P33 sub switch*? Ditto the *DB2 (and DB1) main switch*. Maybe draw a wiring diagram showing them and the cable routing? Add hyper links for the things like P33 and DBn stuff.

Comment: This sounds like ground leakage to me in combination with a shared neutral. How many poles does the sub-switch P33 disconnect ? if only one pole, and the neutral is directly connected it could be that other loads on other circuits have small current leaking to earth. Measure the voltage from each of the socket leads to earth under the different conditions.